# What's an intelligent way of creating a graph like object for the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm?

Tags: java, ford-fulkerson

I'm trying to implement a [Ford–Fulkerson algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) in java and I've been having some problems where my code gets obnoxiously and unnecessarily complicated.

What I do want is to have:

```
class Node:
    private int id
    private static int idAssigner // I may move this to another class
    // etc

class flowNetwork
    private Node source  // begin point
    private Node sink    // end point
```

Now I want to group nodes similarly how I would a (bidirectional) tree. Each node has a list of all nodes it's connected to.

My problem is this: How could I give this connection a value (maximum flow, current flow) ?

Should I make another class `Connection` that has `Node A` `Node B` and `max flow` / `current flow`. And if I do that, how should I connect the nodes ? (as in should every node have a `Connection` and wouldn't that be redundant ? I'm a bit stuck.
**edit** Or should I just have `Connections` and implement some sort of search function to acomodate linking elements. It's all I can think of to be honest.

**P.S.**

This class is mostly just the math part, so I have never implemented a graph, nor does the course cover this, so thank you for helping a novice :) (that's if this doesn't get closed in like 5 minutes).

Comment: Take a look at the [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) library it can be used for modelling nodes and connections as well as visualisation

Comment: This being a homework, I have a very tight scheduled on it, could you please point me towards something in the API ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think, you can use map of linked nodes in each node. With node key and link information as value.

It's not a fast solution, but it's simple.

Faster will be to have a matrix, elements of wich is a link objects, containing all link info. Rows and columns will be node indices.

Comment: And then when I'd like to find a path I'd just look in the matrix (I prefer the matrix approach) and le't say I chose row A, column B meaning A->B and the value is the flow ? And then I'd have another matrix which would represent flow that is used ?

Comment: @Kalec you can have an link object in matrix. It's elements may be not simple weight of link between nodes, and also an current or max flow between nodes.